# How to draw an arrow instead of a dragshadow?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I need the user to drag an arrow between two views, but all info I can find online is to make a dragshadow.

here's an exemple of the result i need.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI37S.jpg

thanks in advance.

Comment: I provided an answer with enough information to point you in the right direction. In the future, you should try to accomplish what you want first and only post a question if you are unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you want requires you to observe touch events inside of your parent ViewGroup, or custom view (whatever is drawing the light-blue grid from the image), using onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) callback. Next, you wanna determine the direction of the drag using the MotionEvent's x and y coordinates and some basic trigonometry. This will allow you to determine the angle of the drag and therefore dynamically the adjust the angle (rotation) of your arrow so that it accurately tracks the finger. Next use the same x and y coordinates you got from the MotionEvent to determine where on the canvas to draw the arrow. If the arrow is another view added as a child, you can set that view's x and y coordinates or translate the view using methods provided by the View class (you may need to play with offset's so the view doesn't get drawn off-screen after several drags/touches). If the arrow is a bitmap our drawable, you will need to adjust the draw coordinates in your view's onDraw(Canvas) method.